# UWP TreeView ItemTempleteSelector is not executed

Tags: xaml, uwp, treeview

TreeView on which I'm working does not execute `ItemTemplateSelector`, no matter I had declared it in XAML and code behind.

Here is my Page resources in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate" x:DataType="localdata:FolderInfo">
        <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind subFolders}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="#Folder#" />
                <Image Width="20" Source="Assets/img2.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind  FolderName }" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate" x:DataType="localdata:FolderInfo">
        <TreeViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Source="Assets/img3.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FolderName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>


    <localdata:ExplorerItemTemplateSelector
        x:Key="ExplorerItemTemplateSelector"
        FolderTemplate="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}"
        FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}" />
```

Here is the `TreeView` declaration, it does use `Style` but it is not of importance to this review:

```
<TreeView   
        x:Name="treeview" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding storageFolders,Mode=OneWay}" 
        Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle1}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExpolrerItemTemplateSelector}"
        >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="localdata:FolderInfo">
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind subFolders}" Content="{x:Bind FolderName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

and in my code behind file:

```
public class ExplorerItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FolderTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FileTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var explorerItem = (FolderInfo)item;
        if (explorerItem.IsFolder == true) return FolderTemplate;

        return FileTemplate;
    }
}
```

Bindings works fine. I had omitted VM from this review to remove clutter. What is also interesting is that if I remove `ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExpolrerItemTemplateSelector}"` from declaration of TreeView, it works without any change in visual or functional sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataTemplateSelector` type actually has two different `SelectTemplateCore` method overloads and `TreeView` uses the second one, with just one `object` parameter:

```
public class ExplorerItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FolderTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FileTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        var explorerItem = (FolderInfo)item;
        if (explorerItem.IsFolder == true) return FolderTemplate;

        return FileTemplate;
    }
}
```

In this form, the method should be called as expected.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Up voted your answer. Had found out that I need to remove ItemTemplate when using selector.